# How do you pronounce "Aeclepiadae"?

Tags: pronunciation, names

Just as the title says.  Or should it really be "Asclepiadae", since it comes from "Asclepius"?

Comment: Where did you find it? It certainly looks like a typo to me.

Comment: Seen in an unpublished work.  There's 7,000 google hits for "aeclepiadae" (versus 38,000 hits for "asclepiadae") so it's not common but also not unheard of.  It may be a typo but it has sure taken on a life of its own!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word that you are asking about was derived by adding (the plural form of) a patronymic suffix to [a Greek name with unknown ultimate etymology](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6495/etymology-of-%E1%BC%88%CF%83%CE%BA%CE%BB%CE%B7%CF%80%CE%B9%CF%8C%CF%82-greek). The a in the second-to-last syllable of patronymics ending in "adae" (including those ending in "iadae") is short as a rule.* The e before the "p" here is long, since the Greek source word is spelled with η. I don't know whether there is any certain way of determining the length of the first "a", or of the "i", but I would guess that both are short, based on my intuitions about the distribution of long and short "a" and "i" in Greek.

The Wikipedia entry on [Asclepius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asclepius) contains a quotation from Beekes that makes the following comments on variant forms of the name:

> The name is typical for Pre-Greek words; apart from minor variations (β for π, αλ(α) for λα) we find α/αι (a well known variation; Fur. 335–339) followed by -γλαπ- or -σκλαπ-/-σχλαπ/β-, i.e. a voiced velar (without -σ-) or a voiceless velar (or an aspirated one: we know that there was no distinction between the three in the substr. language) with a -σ-.

That article also gives "Aesculapius" as a Latin version of the name. Based on this information, I am pretty puzzled by the absence of "s" in the form that you give, but I don't know enough to say anything definite about whether it is a mistake.

The LSJ Greek dictionary has an entry for *[Ἀσκληπιάδαι](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0058%3Aentry%3D*)asklhpia%2Fdai)*, defined as "a name for physicians".
"Asclepiadae", which is simply the regular latinization of "Ἀσκληπιάδαι", certainly seems to be a valid and used form in Latin. If you Google it, you will see a bunch of examples. It would be expected to be pronounced the way it is spelled: i.e., reconstructed Classical Latin pronunciation would be something like [askleːˈpiadae̯], "Ecclesiastical" pronunciation would be something like [asklɛˈpiadɛ], "Traditional English pronunciation" would be /ˌæsklɪˈpaɪədiː/, English anglicized "restored pronunciation" would be something like /ˌɑːskleɪˈpiːədaɪ/.

---

**[Grammar of the Latin Language](https://books.google.com/books?id=OR8XAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=Greek+patronymic+ades),* 64th Ed., Andrews and Stoddard, 1858; §100, p. 49